# Creating a new column in a specific place in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column in Python and place in a specific position. For instance, let "example" be the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd    

example = pd.DataFrame({
            'name': ['alice','bob','charlie'],
            'age': [25,26,27],
            'job': ['manager','clerk','policeman'],
            'gender': ['female','male','male'],
            'nationality': ['french','german','american']
        })
```

I would like to create a new column to contain the values of the column "age":

```
example['age_times_two']= example['age'] *2
```

Yet, this code creates a column at the end of the dataframe. I would like to place it as the third column, or, in other words, the column right next to the column "age". How could this be done:

a) By setting an absolute place to the new column (e.g. third position)?

b) By setting a relative place for the new column (e.g. right to the column "age")?

Comment: what is your desired output look like?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**`df.insert`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) here.

```
example.insert(2,'age_times_two',example['age']*2)
example
      name  age  age_times_two        job  gender nationality
0    alice   25             50    manager  female      french
1      bob   26             52      clerk    male      german
2  charlie   27             54  policeman    male    american
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, I don't use `pd.DataFrame.insert` much at all.  +1 Great answer.

Comment: Bookmarking this question just for 'df.insert' approach. ++1. Great answer, indeed.

Comment: Note that you can only use the insert function once. Running it again will give ValueError.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit manual way of doing it:

```
example['age_times_two']= example['age'] *2

cols = list(example.columns.values)
cols
```

You get a list of all the columns, and you can rearrange them manually and place them in the code below

```
example = example[['name', 'age', 'age_times_two', 'job', 'gender', 'nationality']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
example['age_times_two']= example['age'] *2

cols = example.columns.tolist()

cols = cols[:2]+cols[-1:]+cols[2:-1]

example = example[cols]

print(example)
```

.

```
      name  age  age_times_two        job  gender nationality
0    alice   25             50    manager  female      french
1      bob   26             52      clerk    male      german
2  charlie   27             54  policeman    male    american
```